# Node embeddings for graph query reachability

Tags: graph-theory, reachability

Can we use node embeddings for graph query reachability?
For example, we have a directed graph (G). First, we will calculate the Node embeddings.

Can we check whether node u is reachable to node v using these node embeddings?

Comment: What are node embeddings?  How do you calculate them?

Comment: using Node2Vec or some other algorithm. I have referred - https://towardsdatascience.com/skip-gram-neural-network-for-graphs-83b8f308bf87

Comment: Usually, checking for node reachability is done with a simple depth or breadth first search.  This is fast and needs only a few lines of code.  Whatever node embeddings might be, it is doubtful that this approach would be any improvement.

Comment: Right. DFS/BFS is one option. For better performance, converting the nodes to vectors might be one thought to check the reachability based on the similarity. But Is it possible or not?

Comment: A graph node is not a vector and cannot be converted to a vector.  I think you must be using the term 'node' for something else.  In any case, the reachability has nothing to do with the nodes, but rather is a property of the links between the nodes. You need to clarify your question.